# Android - ListView disappears after setContentView()?

Tags: java, android, xml, listview, android-listview

I have a ListView in one my activity_main.xml file, the problem is, when I click on a Item in that ListView (activity_main.xml), it calls setContentView() and loads another XML file called activity_settings.xml.

The problem is, when I click the back button in activity_settings.xml (Button to call setContentView() again and go back to activity_main.xml) The ListView from activity_main.xml disappears.

I have tried about dozen ways of fixing it, but nothing seems to work.

Here is my MainActivity.java (It is pretty big):

```
package com.NautGames.xectav2.app;

import {...}

public class MainActivity extends ASR {

private ToggleButton homeOnOff;
HomeHoldDown hhd = new HomeHoldDown();

int keyCode;
KeyEvent event;

Context context;

private static final String LOGTAG = "Xecta";
private static final String BOTID = "e38006d97e34053e";

private TTS myTts;
private ImageButton speakButton;
private Bot bot;
Button backB1;
Button backB2;
Button backB3;

boolean mBound = false;

SimpleAdapter simpleAdpt;

BoundService myService = new BoundService();
boolean isBound = false;

EditText name, email, mMessage, subject;

String key;
String Name;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, BoundService.class);
    bindService(intent, myConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

    //homeOnOff = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);

    name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etName);
    email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
    mMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAdd);
    subject = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtSubject);

    Button startBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send);

    backB1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    backB2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    backB3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);

    //Initialize GUI elements
    setSpeakButton();

    //Initialize the speech recognizer
    createRecognizer(getApplicationContext());

    //Initialize text to speech
    myTts = TTS.getInstance(this);

    //Create bot
    bot = new Bot(this, BOTID, myTts, "assistant");

    initList();

    // We get the ListView component from the layout
    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);


    // This is a simple adapter that accepts as parameter
    // Context
    // Data list
    // The row layout that is used during the row creation
    // The keys used to retrieve the data
    // The View id used to show the data. The key number and the view id must match
    simpleAdpt = new SimpleAdapter(this, planetsList, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, new String[] {"page"}, new int[] {android.R.id.text1});


    lv.setAdapter(simpleAdpt);

    // React to user clicks on item
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
    {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parentAdapter, View view, int position,
                                long id)
        {
            // We know the View is a TextView so we can cast it
            TextView clickedView = (TextView) view;

            //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Item with id ["+id+"] - Position ["+position+"] - Planet ["+clickedView.getText()+"]", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if(id == 0)
            {
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
            }

            if(id == 1)
            {
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_about);
            }

            if(id == 2)
            {
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_feedback);
            }

        }
    });
}

public void onClickSend(View v) {

    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    i.setType("message/rfc822");
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{"name@email.com"});
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject.getText().toString());
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , mMessage.getText().toString());
    try {
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail..."));
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "There are no email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}

//from here
private ServiceConnection myConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className,
                                   IBinder service) {
        BoundService.MyLocalBinder binder = (BoundService.MyLocalBinder) service;
        myService = binder.getService();
        isBound = true;
    }

    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
        isBound = false;
    }

};
//to HERE

public void showTime(View view)
{
    myService.getCurrentTime();
}


/************************************************************************
 * WHEN THE USER TURNS THE HOME LISTENING ON AND OFF
 * IT WILL START SERVICE AND STOP SERVICE
 *************************************************************************/
/*public void onToggleClicked(View view) {
    boolean on = ((ToggleButton) view).isChecked();
    if (on) {
        //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Activate Xecta with Home ON", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), Service1.class));
    } else {
        //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Activate Xecta with Home OFF", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //stopService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), LocalService.class));
    }
}*/

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

/*public void onClickService(View view)
{
    if(isApplicationSentToBackground(context))
    {
        hhd.onKeyLongPress(keyCode, event);
    }
}*/

/**************************************************************************
 * WHEN THE USER HOLDS DOWN THE HOME BUTTON
 *************************************************************************/
@Override
public boolean onKeyLongPress(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Key pressed long!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyLongPress(keyCode, event);
}

public void onClickBack(View view)
{
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}

// The data to show
List<Map<String, String>> planetsList = new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();

private void initList() {
    // We populate the planets

    planetsList.add(newList("page", "Settings"));
    planetsList.add(newList("page", "About"));
    planetsList.add(newList("page", "FeedBack"));

}

private HashMap<String, String> newList(String key, String name) {
    HashMap<String, String> planet = new HashMap<String, String>();
    planet.put(key, name);

    return planet;
}

public void onClick(View view)
{
    speakButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.speech_btn);

    try {
        listen(RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_WEB_SEARCH, 10);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"ASR could not be started: invalid params", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.e(LOGTAG, e.getMessage());
    }
}

private void setSpeakButton() {
    speakButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.speech_btn);
    speakButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                listen(RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_WEB_SEARCH, 10);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ASR could not be started: invalid params", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.e(LOGTAG, e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Provides feedback to the user when the ASR encounters an error
 */
public void processAsrError(int errorCode) {

    String errorMessage;
    switch (errorCode)
    {
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_AUDIO:
            errorMessage = "Audio recording error";
            break;
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_CLIENT:
            errorMessage = "Client side error";
            break;
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_PERMISSIONS:
            errorMessage = "Insufficient permissions" ;
            break;
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_NETWORK:
            errorMessage = "Network related error" ;
            break;
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_NETWORK_TIMEOUT:
            errorMessage = "Network operation timeout";
            break;
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_RECOGNIZER_BUSY:
            errorMessage = "RecognitionServiceBusy" ;
            break;
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_SERVER:
            errorMessage = "Server sends error status";
            break;
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_NO_MATCH:
            errorMessage = "No matching message" ;
            break;
        case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_SPEECH_TIMEOUT:
            errorMessage = "Input not audible";
            break;
        default:
            errorMessage = "ASR error";
            break;
    }

    try {
        myTts.speak(errorMessage,"EN");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(LOGTAG, "English not available for TTS, default language used instead");
    }

    //If there is an error, shows feedback to the user and writes it in the log
    Log.e(LOGTAG, "Error: "+ errorMessage);
    Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

public void processAsrReadyForSpeech() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "I'm listening", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

public void processAsrResults(ArrayList<String> nBestList, float[] confidences) {
    String bestResult = nBestList.get(0);
    Log.d(LOGTAG, "Speech input: " + bestResult);
    // insert %20 for spaces in query
    bestResult = bestResult.replaceAll(" ", "%20");

    bot.initiateQuery(bestResult);

    //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    myTts.shutdown();
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    newList(key, Name);
    initList();
}

@Override
public void onStop()
{
    super.onStop();
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Bye bye!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    onKeyLongPress(keyCode, event);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

}
```

onClickBack is the button to go back to activity_main.xml, I am also initialising the ListView in onCreate().

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/onericblur"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="5dp"
android:onClick="onClick"
android:weightSum="1">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:paddingBottom="10dip"
    android:paddingTop="10dip"
    android:text="@string/title"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

 </LinearLayout>

<ViewAnimator
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/viewAnimator"
    android:layout_gravity="right" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/speech_btn"
    android:background="@null"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/xectaicon"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top" />

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="127dp"
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_weight="1.22"
    android:background="@android:drawable/screen_background_light_transparent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And activity_settings...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:weightSum="1"
android:background="@drawable/onericblur">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="?android:attr/listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
    android:text="Settings"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="291dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Xecta is currently in Beta being tested, you can request settings by going to the feedback section. Sorry!"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_weight="0.04"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:gravity="center|top" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Back to home"
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:onClick="onClickBack"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

</LinearLayout>
```

What could be causing the problem?!?!?

Thanks.

Comment: How would I start new activities? @MikeM. Sorry I'm new to Java.

Comment: Simply write all your `onCreate()` methods code into `onResume()` i think your listview does not show because of the data is not binded into it. So just try to write all the data binding code into `onResume()` and check out.

Comment: Thanks @GrlsHu , I added `@Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        lv.setAdapter(simpleAdpt);
    }` But this didn't work.

Comment: @SnowboardingProgrammer Check out my answer and try accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by Ram Kiran, it's better to have different activities for Settings / Home.

The problem with the code you have posted is that you are not populating the list with the contents when you press back. I believe it should be fixed with the following code,

```
public void onClickBack(View view)
{
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    lv.setAdapter(simpleAdpt);

}
```

Basically when you call setContentView(layoutId) new view will be inflated from the layout and you need to do all the UI lookup, initialization again.

Comment: One problem, When I click on the items after setContentView() they dont do anything.

Comment: As I have mentioned earlier, setContentView will be inflating new view from layout which won't be having any content / listeners associated with it .You need to do all the UI related initializations like adding listeners, feeding the adapter with the content,etc., after call to every setContentView(resourceId). Alternatively if you want to avoid all those stuff you can have a view object at class level by inflating the layout using [LayoutInflater](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html#inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup)   and then do setContentView(view)

Answer (score 0):

I dont think loading xml files repeatedly in same activity is a good one. Try to use two activities instead of loading different xml files in same activity.

### MainActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

ListView lv = (ListView) findviewById(R.id.list);

lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
{
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parentAdapter, View view, int position,
                            long id)
    {

        Intent n = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SettingsActivity.class);
        startActivity(n);
    }
}
```

### SettingsActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Buttoon btn = (Button) findviewById(R.id.btn);
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent n = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(n);
         }
     });
```

Comment: yes you can do that by calling finish() instead of starting new activity also

Answer (score 0):

Try out as below:

```
@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, BoundService.class);
    bindService(intent, myConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

    //homeOnOff = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);

    name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etName);
    email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
    mMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAdd);
    subject = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtSubject);

    Button startBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send);

    backB1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    backB2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    backB3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);

    //Initialize GUI elements
    setSpeakButton();

    //Initialize the speech recognizer
    createRecognizer(getApplicationContext());

    //Initialize text to speech
    myTts = TTS.getInstance(this);

    //Create bot
    bot = new Bot(this, BOTID, myTts, "assistant");

    initList();

    // We get the ListView component from the layout
    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);


    // This is a simple adapter that accepts as parameter
    // Context
    // Data list
    // The row layout that is used during the row creation
    // The keys used to retrieve the data
    // The View id used to show the data. The key number and the view id must match
    simpleAdpt = new SimpleAdapter(this, planetsList, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, new String[] {"page"}, new int[] {android.R.id.text1});


    lv.setAdapter(simpleAdpt);

}
```